# Show that the function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

let $A \subset \Bbb R$ be a measurable st and $f_n: A \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Show the function is measurable:
$$f(x)=\inf_{n \in \Bbb N} f_n(x)$$

I started it of like this but I don't know how to proceed:
$x\in f^{-1}\big((-\infty,a)\big) \Leftrightarrow f(x)\in \big((-\infty,a)\big) \Leftrightarrow \inf_{n \in \Bbb N} f_n(x)\in \big((-\infty,a)\big) \Leftrightarrow ...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show that $f^{-1}((-\infty , a])=\cup f_n^{-1}((-\infty , a])$

=================================================

$x\in f^{-1}(-\infty , a]\leftrightarrow f(x)=inf f_n(x)\leq a\leftrightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{N} s.t. f_n(x)\leq a\leftrightarrow \exists n s.t. x\in f_n^{-1}(-\infty, a]\leftrightarrow x\in \cup f_n^{-1}(-\infty, a]$

Comment: could you elaborate on it, please?

Comment: @Max: I added something. Is it clear for you?

Comment: so easy, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Justo note that
$$
\{x\in A\mid f(x)\geq a\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{x\in A\mid f_n(x)\geq a\}
$$
And use whatever you know about measurable functions and $\sigma$-algebras.